# MapView within ExpandableListView

Tags: android, google-maps

In my `ExpandableListView` I need to add Google Map on each item.

I tried with putting Map on each item but its giving me inflate exception. And its is also stated that an MapActivity can contain only one MapView.

Is there any other idea to achieve this.

For refrence you can see [here.](http://www.automatic.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments regarding `MapActivity` indicate that you are using Maps V1, which is deprecated. Maps V2 does not require a `MapActivity` and can have multiple maps.

That being said, your proposed implementation is unlikely to work well, as putting scrollable things in scrollable things can be problematic. It also is rather unrealisitc IMHO -- whoever came up with that design has never used an actual smartphone, as there's no point in having an interactive map that small (again, IMHO).

Consider using static maps (there's a Google API for that somewhere) for inside the `ExpandableListView`, where a tap on the map brings up the full map, either in your app or in the standard Maps app.

Comment: but then how to place a custom marker on the static map? it is possible to show it but only in case it's placed in the center of the static map (just show a drawable on top of static map. if you want to place marker not in the center but in certain lat/lon then static map is useless.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch: I have never used Google's static maps API, so I would recommend that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question to get assistance with marker placement.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to not use static map (as for example it's not possible to zoom to particular bounds with [newLatLngBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds,%20int%29) or [add a circle](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addCircle%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions%29) in particular lat/lon).

I recommend to use [map fragment in lite mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html):

> In addition, there is also a new ‘lite mode’ map option, ideal for situations where you want to provide a number of smaller maps, or a map that is so small that meaningful interaction is impractical, such as a thumbnail in a list. A lite mode map is a bitmap image of a map at a specified location and zoom level.

Map fragment can be [nested](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) in the list.

Comment: Beware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28106979/google-map-lite-mode-movecamera-to-lat-lng-bounds-adds-unwanted-map-padding/28187377#28187377