# Google Map Lite Mode moveCamera to lat lng bounds adds unwanted map padding

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I want map camera to move to my LatLngBounds. So I add map fragment to layout in `BaseExpandableListAdapter`'s `getChildView` and `onMapReady` I'll `moveCamera` to `LatLngBounds`

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_child, parent, false);

    GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions();
    options.liteMode(true)
           .compassEnabled(false)
           .mapToolbarEnabled(false)
           .rotateGesturesEnabled(false)
           .tiltGesturesEnabled(false)
           .scrollGesturesEnabled(false)
           .zoomControlsEnabled(false)
           .zoomGesturesEnabled(false);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance(options);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.event_fragment_map, mapFragment, "event_fragment_map").commit();

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            moveMapAddBounds();
        }
    });

//...
}

private void moveMapAddBounds(){
    mGoogleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(getLatLngBounds().southwest)
                                              .add(new LatLng(getLatLngBounds().northeast.latitude, getLatLngBounds().southwest.longitude))
                                              .add(getLatLngBounds().northeast)
                                              .add(new LatLng(getLatLngBounds().southwest.latitude, getLatLngBounds().northeast.longitude))
                         );
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getLatLngBounds(), 0));
}

public LatLngBounds getLatLngBounds() {
    //random fake latlng and distance
    LatLng from = new LatLng(51.1113564, 17.0041787);
    double distance = 1717.906494140625;
    return new LatLngBounds.Builder().
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(from, distance, 0)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(from, distance, 90)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(from, distance, 180)).
            include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(from, distance, 270)).build();
}
```

I'm calculating bounds according to [http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5704) and it seems to work OK as the rectangle added to map in `moveMapAddBounds` is added in valid positions but the map camera is moved to almost good position with the exception that it adds a random (?) paddings to map (symmetric above and below the rectangle) as seen on picture:

[image]

I've observed that those paddings are always the same for a particular LatLngBounds but they differ between different LatLngBounds.

Comment: probable reason of this behavior: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7573&q=apitype%3AAndroid2%20type%3ADefect&sort=-id%20-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was I used Lite Mode where only integer zooms are available.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7573&q=apitype%3AAndroid2%20type%3ADefect&sort=-id%20-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars